# Maven site generation using advanced Markdown?

Tags: maven, markdown, maven-site-plugin, doxia, flexmark

We are using Markdown in our [Maven generated site](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/index.html). Works like a charm. AFAIK the plugin uses [Flexmark](https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java) under the hood, which supports the [Admonition extensions](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/extensions/admonition/).

We would like to use them too, the infoboxes are quite helpful for documentation. Our site configuration in the `pom.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.2</version>
</plugin>
```

How could we configure it to recognise the additional markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a little old but I have been trying to figure this out for using the Gitlab extension for math equations and the short answer is I don't think you can do it out of the box.

The maven-site-plugin uses the [doxia-module-markdown](https://github.com/apache/maven-doxia/tree/doxia-1.11.1/doxia-modules/doxia-module-markdown) module for markdown which uses Flexmark internally but it is pre-configured with the extensions that it uses for this.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/apache/maven-doxia/blob/doxia-1.11.1/doxia-modules/doxia-module-markdown/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/doxia/module/markdown/MarkdownParser.java) to the code and the exact snippet from

```java
// Initialize the Flexmark parser and renderer, once and for all
static
{
    MutableDataSet flexmarkOptions = new MutableDataSet();

    // Enable the extensions that we used to have in Pegdown
    flexmarkOptions.set( com.vladsch.flexmark.parser.Parser.EXTENSIONS, Arrays.asList(
            EscapedCharacterExtension.create(),
            AbbreviationExtension.create(),
            AutolinkExtension.create(),
            DefinitionExtension.create(),
            TypographicExtension.create(),
            TablesExtension.create(),
            WikiLinkExtension.create(),
            StrikethroughExtension.create()
    ) );

// ...
}
```

I think that you could possibly fork this project, add the extensions you need, and add it as a dependency to the maven-site-plugin and it might work like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${my-forked-groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${my-forked-artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${my-forked-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

This in my opinion is less than ideal and I will probably be exploring other (non-maven) options to get the result I'm looking for but will probably still try this out in the next day or so and if I get it working I'll send a link to the code in case anybody else can benefit from it.

Comment: So I did try out what I mentioned above, forked the repository and added the Gitlab extension to flexmakrOptions, and then updated the dependencies to the maven-site-plugin.  This actually worked pretty well.